# reading textfile and saving theinfo into and array of array in perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have a text file which contains following code. I want create perl code to read that containt and form a corresponding data structure in perl. I can read the **.txt** file with below perl code  but how to read and save that all in perl data structur like `Arrays of arrays/Hashes of arrays/Arrays of hashes/Hashes of hashes` , anybody can help me?

```
{
   "Availability" : {
      "142" : {
         "141" : "1.042",
         "161" : "0.000",
         "162" : "0.000"
      }
   },
   "Average Jitter to Destination" : {
      "142" : {
         "141" : "192.309",
         "161" : "13.323",
         "162" : "37.003"
      }
   },
   "Average Jitter to Source" : {
      "142" : {
         "141" : "192.309",
         "161" : "13.323",
         "162" : "37.003"
      }
   },
   "Average Round Trip Time" : {
      "142" : {
         "141" : "8557.511",
         "161" : "772.278",
         "162" : "389.566"
      }
   },
   "Packet Loss to Destination" : {
      "142" : {
         "141" : "0.000",
         "161" : "0.000",
         "162" : "0.000"
      }
   },
   "Packet Loss to Source" : {
      "142" : {
         "141" : "0.000",
         "161" : "0.000",
         "162" : "0.000"
      }
   }
```

For above I wrote code:

```
print "content-type: text/html \n\n"; #HTTP HEADER
$dirname = "/ravikiran/html/JSONData.txt";
$dirpath = "$ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$dirname";
sysopen(HANDLE, $dirpath , O_RDWR);
my %data;`enter code here`
while($line = <HANDLE>) {
chomp $line;
print $line;
}
close (HANDLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

The input looks like JSON. Use the appropriate module:

```
use JSON;
my $s = from_json(join q(), <>);
```

Comment: thanks can u elobrate it plz i am new in perl . can u tell me the regular expression for this

Comment: @ravikiran: There is no regular expression. Run `cpan JSON` and use my script, `$s` will contain the structure you request.

Comment: How about `my $s;{local $/;$s = from_json(<>)}`